# how to make a call if the number to dial has "/" and "to" conjunction?

Tags: android, phone-number

I have an activity that displays a list view of all hospitals in an area with details such as name, address, area, contact, persons tel numbers, emails address and more.

When the user clicks one of the item in the list, it will call the numbers in the tel number category. But i have a slight problem when calling tel number, when the number has conjunction **"/"** for example **234-2342/234-2431**. The programs dials this as **234-2342234-2431** which is a wrong number. And **"to"** for example **234-5678 to 81** and dials it as **234-567881** which also a wrong number.

The project can't distinguish the number to dial and dials all the number but when the conjunction is **","** for example **234-2342 , 234-2431** the program dials the first number that appears which is **234-2342** any suggestions?

Comment: Please format your question and use dots and commas!

Comment: sorry about that i fixed it i hope you can now read it.

Comment: wouldnt call that "fixed" : D

Comment: well i think you know what i mean already right?what i did was to change action_call to action_dial but the user will still have a problem which number to erase if the project dial 234-2342234-2431 is there a way to make the program tell how to call number with conjunction?

Comment: you should replace those characters using String.replace() or any other method of String.

Comment: string.replace("/", ",");
string.replace("to", ",");

Comment: what should be dialed for all the conditions? can you give your requirement? when number has "/" then what should be dialed and same for "to" and ",".

Comment: if the conjunction is "/" or "to" you can just dial the first number when "," this is the conjunction the programs works fine because it dials the first number and its ok. my problems is with "/" and "to" because it combines the numbers making it a wrong number.. i really didnt think of making condition on which number to dial lol can you give an example of that?